# When I pull the trigger on my cream whipper, it won't stop, even when released

Tags: whipped-cream, whipper

I have an isi gourmet whip, 1/2 liter. I prepare a standard preparation of whipped cream, meaning cream, some sugar, and a bit of vanilla extract, pressurize the canister, shake, and then when I go to discharge it, it discharges, but won't stop discharging, even when the handle is released. I've cleaned the spout thoroughly, checked the o-ring, and everything seems to be in order

Comment: Does the handle spring back to its original position when it's released?  If not, there's probably a spring that's not doing its job any more.  (it might still have the same strength, but there might be friction somewhere)

Comment: I once had a soda bottle that was doing this... It happened when I changed brands of soda cartridge... I just had to giggle the handle to ensure that it had sprung back all the way... When I switched back to the original brand the problem went away. I don't know if this is the case, but Joe's suggestion reminded me of the problem... It turned out that it was a case that my canister's cartridge holder was sensitive to the size of cartridge used, and this one was just a little off spec causing it to continue to force gas into the canister and not allow the valve to return to the closed position.

Comment: @joe: Yes, the handle springs back to where its supposed to.


After a significant amount of the contents has discharged, it returns to normal behavior


I'll have to try detaching the gas once i've charged it, although I am using OEM cartridges